# free shipping under £100 and on specific item

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, shipping-methods

I am looking for some help, I have tried a few different ways but I cant seem to get it to work the way I want it.

I want to set up free shipping for items that are under £100 and for a specific item.

Could someone give me an example of how best to achieve this please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work in the end by enabling the free shipping option in **System > Configuration > Shipping Methods**

Answer (score 0):

As in default you can set the **Minimum Order Amount** for whole cart here

inside  `Admin->System->Configuration->Shipping Methods->Free shipping`

For **specific item** just create one shopping cart rule

Admin->Promotions->Shopping Cart price Rule. Just like the screenshots.
[image]
[image]